# Why is there a drop in the amount of Ether I transferred

Tags: gas, gas-price

I tried to transfer 1.37299 Ether from one account to another. In the process, 0.0004851 Ether was consumed as gas. Even subtracting this gas price, ideally, 1.3725049 Ether should be transferred to my other account. But I find that only 1.36299 Ether is transferred. [Here is the transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfe27c7d572de62ed05ac30f056b205d1de5465a934a77dcecc752631735a9ea4). Why is there a drop in the amount of Ether? Am I ever going to recover it?

[image]

[image]

I am new to Ethereum and Ether. I understand the basics of gas cost and gas price associated with getting my transaction on the blockchain. Can someone please clarify this. Thank you.

Comment: What wallet have you used to create and send the transaction? In the tx itself there is no mention of the amounts 1.37xxxx you are talking about.

Comment: @MichałKłeczek Thanks for pointing it out. I added the info in the question now. I used cex.io for buying the Ether and transferring them

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have done a withdrawal from one of the exchanges and most likely the difference is the fee that the exchange takes upon withdrawal.

Check the fees and policies of the exchange.

Transferring ether from your own account is free (except gas costs).